# Configuration of Unity IoC with Web API 4.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I'm trying to configure Unity IoC in ASP.NET Web Api project. I have made installation of Unity.WebAPI package:

> PM > Install-Package Unity.MVC4

And added the next code to `Initialise` method of `Bootstrapper` class:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

Also I have registered my repository in container:

```
container.RegisterType<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
```

But my App crashes with the error `Type 'MvcApplication1.Controllers.ValuesController' does not have a default constructor.`
Could someone point me out what have I missed? I use .Net Framework 4.5. Which  package of Unity is OK for my purposes (Unity.WebAPI, Unity.MVC4, ...)?

**Updated:** Injection of repository into controller:

```
private readonly IProductRepository _repository;

public ValuesController(IProductRepository repository)
{
    _repository = repository;
}
```

Comment: i think you should add your code of `ValuesController` as well as it seems the error is in conjunction with that, what methods are there inside that controller, which one did you (try to) call?

Comment: Oops! I'm sorry, just updated.

Comment: wait a second! First you say `I have made installation of Unity.WebAPI`, but then you install `Unity.MVC4` which one was it now, what are you building? MVC application or Web API application?

Comment: I'm working on Web API project, but installed package is Unity.MVC4. Actually I've tried to install Unity.WebAPI but after installation I found compile errors: 'MvcApplication1.Areas.HelpPage.XmlDocumentationProvider' does not implement interface member 'System.Web.Http.Description.IDocumentationProvider.GetResponseDocumentation(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor)' ...\MvcApplication1\Areas\HelpPage\XmlDocumentationProvider.cs 

As a result I have no idea how to workaround it...

Comment: did you try what i suggested you in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did looks good so far, but I think you are missing just this one line

```
Bootstrapper.Initialise();
```

This should go into the startup code of your application `Global.asax.cs` for MVC-Applications for example, just put it there at the end inside of this method

```
protected void Application_Start()
```

Comment: Yeah! Thank you, it was pretty funny omission :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are following this article. If not, it could help you out.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver

Regarding the error, try adding a constructor to the controller with no parameters:

i.e.

```
public ValuesController()
{

}
```

Comment: I don't need parameterless constructor because I have to inject the repository into controller...

Comment: My apologies, you are correct. 

I just mentioned the parameterless constructor because it looks like that somewhere in the code is expected to be available the default constructor of the controller, which is a constructor with no parameters.

Comment: @emendezrivas Just to add some clarification to that. What you describe is true for the default behavior. Unity's IoC however should override that behavior in the sense that Unity will always try to match the constructor with the biggest number of parameters. So in every other case you would have been right, but when it comes to IoC you have to "switch" in your head that the default behavior should be different => i.e. configuration error.